# Adaptive Card/ Actionable message in Shared Mailbox?

Tags: outlook, office365, adaptive-cards, office365connectors

Im trying out Actionable message (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/) and sending it out to Shared Mailbox on Outlook on the web for Office 365. However, the results doesnt show/generate the Actionable Message button when compared to when im sending to my own outlook. It produces the words only. Approved/Reject

Just wondering is it supported?

Thanks.

Comment: [Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/#release-notes) suggests it is supported in Outlook on the Web. If you provide code, it will be easier for help to be provided (always recommended, btw).

Comment: @StevenKanberg Apologize for not providing the code however ive asked on Microsoft Community and got a reply stating that since Shared Mailbox is kind of a group, its not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email

Answer (score 0):

Since Shared Mailbox is kind of a group, Actionable Message is not supported. Clarified by asking on Microsoft Community.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email